# Equivalent of ObserveOnDispatcher in Blazor

Tags: c#, multithreading, blazor, system.reactive, blazor-server-side

In Blazor, there is no single UI thread and as far as I know no dispatcher.
There is `ComponentBase.InvokeAsync(..)` however:

```
protected Task InvokeAsync(Action workItem);
protected Task InvokeAsync(Func<Task> workItem);
```

How do I switch from non-ui thread to UI thread?

```
IObservable<int> source ...
source.Throttle(100) // will continue on non UI thread
  .ObserveOnComponent() // how do I write this?
  .ObserveOn(this.InvokeAsync) // or this?
  .Do(this.StateHasChanged); // something that requires UI thread
  .Subscribe();
```

Comment: Blazor Server or Blazor Wasm?

Comment: At least in server version there are both dispatcher and synchronization context.

Comment: It's blazor Server. Ok, but how do I access it?

Comment: I cannot test right now, but I'd expect SynchronizationContext.Current to be not null, and there is ObserveOn overload which accepts sync context